# jQuery $this and find selectors not working properly

Tags: php, jquery

I have an onclick function inside for loop in PHP.
I want to show particular DIV when I click on particular onclick function.

These are my codes.

This is PHP code

```
for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    echo '<a href onclick="get_number($i)">Get Number</a>';
    echo '<div class="ans_option_box" style="display:none">show this div</div>';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

This is jQuery code

```
<script>
function get_number(id)
{
     $(this).find('.ans_option_box').show();
}
</script>
```

I really want, when I click on 5th onclick value. DIV should appear under 5th value.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need double quotes `"` around the PHP string to interpolate `$i`.

Comment: Use `button` elements instead of `a`, or try to control the click event in the script to prevent default, because when you click on the `a`, the page will be reloaded and you won't see any div.

Comment: Hi, 
PHP code is not a problem. My problem is jquery one.
that is not really PHP code I am using. I have put that only to get an idea.
I really want, when I click on 5th onclick value. DIV should appear under 5th value like that

Comment: @nanocv - function is working, if I put an alert inside it, it is working, but div particular div show function is not working. If I remove this selector, it will show all divs

Comment: do you know the difference between clientside and serverside functions? Your *"I have put that only to get an idea"* is throwing people off here and doesn't support the question.

Answer (score 0):

The div you want to show isn't a child of the `<a>` tag, so `find()` won't work. You will have to change your html or use a different jQuery function.

And you need to change `echo '<a href onclick="get_number($i)">Get Number</a>';` to `echo '<a href onclick="get_number(' . $i . ')">Get Number</a>';` to actually have php output the number.

Comment: Hi, PHP code is not a problem. My problem is jquery one. that is not really PHP code I am using. I have put that only to get an idea. I really want, when I click on 5th onclick value. DIV should appear under 5th value like that

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it working. You have to change the PHP code to display `$i` correctly.

Also, I changed the jQuery selector to search items by id, because it's easier and much more efficient.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php
    for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
      echo '<button onclick="get_number(' . $i . ')">Get Number</button>';
      echo '<div id="' . $i . '" class="ans_option_box" style="display:none">show this div</div>';
      echo '<br>';
    }
    ?>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function get_number(id)
      {
        $("#"+id).show();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```